# Set mandatory variable on Flutter class in Dart with interface

Tags: flutter, dart, interface

Setting up multiple theme on a new Flutter project. I'm looking for doing it more consistently by implementing an Interface or something in the idea.

I currently have this class

```
/// Theme constant class
class AppTheme{
  AppTheme._();

  /// The default blue app theme
  static final ThemeData blueTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  );

  /// Brown theme
  static final ThemeData brownTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.green,
  );

  /// Elevation
  static final List<BoxShadow> elevation = [
    const BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black12,
      offset: Offset(0, 9),
      blurRadius: 28,
      spreadRadius: 8,
    ),
    const BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black12,
      offset: Offset(0, 6),
      blurRadius: 16,
    ),
    const BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black12,
      offset: Offset(0, 3),
      blurRadius: 6,
      spreadRadius: -4,
    ),
  ];
}
```

I looking for a way to define blueTheme and brownTheme that implement the same variable.

Here we can see that blueTheme has a backgroundColor but brown not and this is my problem.

Is here any solution to have a template that set mandatory field when you create a new ThemeData for example a new greenTheme variable?

PS: I left elevation here to show you that it's possible to have other types and not only ThemeDatas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so today I found a solution

I create a new class called **AppThemeInterface** and set inside a ThemeData type and set it in the constructor.

After trying several methods to implement the theme data and recreate a factory constructor, I got an error during compilation.

Here is the most straight forward solution I got.

```
class AppThemeInterface {
  late ThemeData theme;

  AppThemeInterface({
    required Color primaryColor,
    required Color backgroundColor,
  }) {
    theme = ThemeData(
          primaryColor: primaryColor,
          backgroundColor: backgroundColor,
     );
  }
}
```

then changed the ThemeData type to my AppThemeInterface and call the "theme" variable

```
class AppTheme{
  AppTheme._();

  /// The default blue app theme
  static final ThemeData blueTheme = AppThemeInterface ( // <=== here
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  ).theme;// <=== here

  /// Brown theme
  static final ThemeData brownTheme = AppThemeInterface ( // <=== here
    primaryColor: Colors.green,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  ).theme; // <=== here
}
```

I'm not sure about my naming but it works as I intended and I hope it helps others who need to set a mandatory field for ThemeData so they don't forget a variable when creating multiple themes.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of Colors.transparent where ever you don't want to use color for the App.

Example: `/// Theme constant class

```
class AppTheme{
  AppTheme._();

  /// The default blue app theme
  static final ThemeData blueTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.blue,
    backgroundColor: Colors.black,
  );

  /// Brown theme
  static final ThemeData brownTheme = ThemeData(
    primaryColor: Colors.green,
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
  );

  /// Elevation
  static final List<BoxShadow> elevation = [
    const BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black12,
      offset: Offset(0, 9),
      blurRadius: 28,
      spreadRadius: 8,
    ),
    const BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black12,
      offset: Offset(0, 6),
      blurRadius: 16,
    ),
    const BoxShadow(
      color: Colors.black12,
      offset: Offset(0, 3),
      blurRadius: 6,
      spreadRadius: -4,
    ),
  ];
}
```

`

Comment: Sorry I was not enough clear in my demand. But what I want is to force to use primaryColor and backgroundColor in all ThemeData I would create (like an interface) and when I add a new definition (example colorScheme) I have to add it on all themes.